# Calculate majority element in an array

Tags: algorithm

Last week I appeared in an interview. I was given the following question:

> Given an array of 2n elements, and out of this n elements are same, and the remaining are all different. Find the element that repeats n times.
>
> There is no restriction on the range of the elements.

Can someone please give me an efficient algorithm to solve this?

Comment: **<from deleted answer>** See [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Array of 2n elements is given, and out of this n elements are same, and remaining are all different. Find the element that repeats n time."

This can be done in O(n) with the following algorithm:

1) Iterate over the array, checking to see if any elements [i] and [i+1] are the same.

2) Iterate over the array, checking to see if any elements [i] and [i+2] are the same.

3) If n = 2 (and thus length = 4), check if 0 and 3 are the same.

Explanation:

Call the matching elements m and the non-matching elements r.

For n = 2, we can construct mmrr, mrmr and mrrm - so we must check for gap size 0, 1 and the only place we can have gap size 2.

For n > 2, we cannot construct the array with no gaps of size 0 or 1. For example for n = 3, you have to start like this: mrrmr... but then you must place an m. Similarly for n = 4, mrrmrrmm - having no gaps of size 0 or 1 would require ms to be outnumbered by rs by more and more as n increases. Proving this is easy.

Comment: Can you give me that proof. Actually requires mathematics, and some statements. Can you tell me that?

Comment: @devsda It's a trivial proof by contradiction.

Comment: This is a good idea, and asympotically optimal, but you can get more leverage if step 1 does not succeed (does not contain a consecutive pair).  Specifically if it does not, the target element must be identifiable using only the first four elements.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to find two elements that are the same.

One idea would be:

Get one element from the 2n elements.
If it is not in the a Set, put it in.
Repeat until you find one that is in that set.

Comment: I didn't get your second point. Please explain again "If it is not in the a Set, put it in."

Comment: You need to remember the numbers you already got. ie put them in the set.

Comment: This seems like the best option. The problem basically states that there are N+1 different numbers of which one repeats N times. The odds that the next element chosen is not already in the set only drops as more are added to the set and as N gets larger, so on average this should do much better than O(N). Then again that might mean that this isn't strictly O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Well if complexity doesn't matter, one naive way would be to use two loops, which is for the worst case O(n^2).

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j++){
        if(array[i] == array[j]){
           // element found
    }
}
```

Comment: In interview questions like this, complexity specifically does matter.  They want ideally an asymptotically optimal solution, preferably with a single pass, and a sketch of a proof for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

If the first four elements are all distinct then the array must contain a consecutive pair of the target element...

```
int find(int A[n])
{
    // check first four elements (10 iterations = O(1))
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       for (int j = i+1; j < 4; j++)
          if (A[i] == A[j])
              return A[i];

    // find the consecutive pair (n-4 iterations = O(n))
    for (int i = 3; i < n-1; i++)
        if (A[i] == A[i+1])
            return A[i];

    // unreachable if input matches preconditions
    throw invald_input;
}
```

This is optimally O(n) time with a single pass and O(1) space.

Answer (score 0):

If you find one element twice, that is the element as the questions says : Array of 2n elements is given, **and out of this n elements are same, and remaining are all different**. Find the element that repeats n time.

Comment: How will you keep track of the elements so you know whether you found any given element before?

Answer (score 0):

You have array of 2n element and half are same and remaining are different so , consider following case,

```
ARRAY[2n] = {N,10,N,878,85778,N......};
```

or

```
Array[2n] = {10,N,10,N,44,N......};
```

And so on now simple case in for loop like,

```
if(ARRAY[i] == ARRAY[i+1])
{
         //Your similar element :)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `1,2,1,3,1,4`. You need to check `i+2` as well, as in [Patashu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16872680/1711796).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem should be "find the element that appears at least n+1 times", if it appears only n times they can be two.

Assuming that there is such an element in the input the following algorithm can be used.

```
input array of 2*n elements;

int candidate = input[0];
int count = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < 2*n; ++i) {
    if (input[i] == candidate) {
         count++;
    } else {
         count --;
         if (count == 0) candidate = input[i];
    }
}

return candidate;
```

if the request is to find if there is an element present n+1 times another traversal is required to find if the element found at previous step appears n + 1 times.

**Edit:**

It has been suggested that the n elements with the same value are contiguous.
If this is the case just use the above algorithm and stop when count reaches n.

Comment: The question states that all remaining elements are different. So it appearing n times is fine.

Comment: This does not work.  Consider `{1,2,1,3}`.  Your program will incorrectly output 3.  Further I believe there is a logic error in your count handling.  This algorithm is from Fisher-Salzberg (1982) "Finding a majority among n votes." Journal of Algorithms 3, pp 143-152.  While it could be adapted, it fails to take advantage of the other half of the elements being all distinct.

Comment: @user1131467 the questions does not suggest to me that n elements with the same value are contiguous. Given this the problem should state the it should appear n+1 times. If they are contiguous it is very simple, just use the above algo and stop when count is equal to n.

Comment: @MariusBucur: Your last comment is nonsensical to the point of being incomprehensible.  Please organize your thoughts and try again.